# Variable not initialised

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to write a menu to handle my classes for an assignment. I have the classes I want to try but I seem to have a problem creating the menu.

```
 switch(choice)
 {
    case 1:
        System.out.print("Please enter a filename: ");
        filename = option.next();

         //creating objects of the file manager to open the required files
        FileManager e = new FileManager("Z:\\Java\\College\\Robo-Reader\\src\\"+filename+".txt");
        FileManager e1 = new FileManager("Z:\\Java\\College\\Robo-Reader\\src\\punctuation.txt");

        //creating connection to the files
        e.connectToFile();
        e1.connectToFile();

        //Reading the files
        String[] fileToBeRead= e.readFile();
        String[] punctMarks = e1.readFile();

        //closing the files
        e.closeReadFile();
        e1.closeReadFile();
        fileRead++;
        break;

    case 2:

        if(fileRead == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No file was read. Please open a file to correct this error:");

        }
        else
        {
            FindLan t3 = new FindLan(fileToBeRead);
            t3.cLang();
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        if(fileRead == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No file was read. Please open a file to correct this error:");

        }
        else
        {

            //Creating the object for the remove punctuation class
            RemovePunct t1 = new RemovePunct(punctMarks, fileToBeRead);

            //Calling the EndArray(Remove) method to clean an array of punctuation marks
            String[] cleanWords = t1.EndArray();

             for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
             {
                System.out.println(cleanWords[i]);
             }
        }
    default:
        System.out.println("Option is not available");
 }
```

So I need to be able to use the variables from  case 1 in case 2 and 3 but I need them initialized in case 1 to get the length of the array.

So far I tried to use a try/catch block but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any other ideas on how I could used the initialised values from case one in the other cases without having to give them a value in case 2/3?

The main goal is to be able to use the arrays defined in case 1 that get their size and elements from the filemanager class and use them in the other 2 cases without me having to define size or elements.

Comment: The overall goal is to have the arrays receive their size from my file manager class. I am setting the size and elements in there and returning it therefore i can't initialize it outside the switch. furthermore i need to use those returned arrays in the case2, case 3 for my other classes. So i want to be able to use the two arrays from case 1 in case2 and case3 without having to give them a value myself

Answer (score 2):

Move the variable declarations outside the switch statement like this:

```
FileManager e = null;
FileManager e1 = null;
String[] fileToBeRead;
String[] punctMarks;

switch(choice)
{
    case 1:
        System.out.print("Please enter a filename: ");
        filename = option.next();

         //creating objects of the file manager to open the required files
        e = new FileManager("Z:\\Java\\College\\Robo-Reader\\src\\"+filename+".txt");
        e1 = new FileManager("Z:\\Java\\College\\Robo-Reader\\src\\punctuation.txt");

        //creating connection to the files
        e.connectToFile();
        e1.connectToFile();

        //Reading the files
        fileToBeRead= e.readFile();
        punctMarks = e1.readFile();

        //closing the files
        e.closeReadFile();
        e1.closeReadFile();
        fileRead++;
        break;

    case 2:

        if(fileRead == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No file was read. Please open a file to correct this error:");

        }
        else
        {
            FindLan t3 = new FindLan(fileToBeRead);
            t3.cLang();
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        if(fileRead == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No file was read. Please open a file to correct this error:");

        }
        else
        {

            //Creating the object for the remove punctuation class
            RemovePunct t1 = new RemovePunct(punctMarks, fileToBeRead);

            //Calling the EndArray(Remove) method to clean an array of punctuation marks
            String[] cleanWords = t1.EndArray();

             for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
             {
                System.out.println(cleanWords[i]);
             }
        }
    default:
        System.out.println("Option is not available");
 }
```

Comment: It is not enough. It will not pass compiler since again variables can be not initialized. One of the way is to give them null values at the declaration. like `FileManager e = null;` It will pass compiler, but it needs to handle situation in `case 2 and 3` when variable is null.

Comment: It's fine thank you I just needed to bypass the compiler error I will use ifs to make sure that the variables are initialised. Thanks a lot.